# Determine if folder have a file or not in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Simple thing I want to do but,
I try to do this with no success

```
@echo off

:start
if not exist "input" mkdir input

if not exist input\* echo Please put a file in "input" folder. && pause && goto start 

echo there is a file in "input" folder.
pause
```

Any help to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to list files and see if it finds some:

```
dir /b /a-d input\* >nul 2>&1 && echo there is a file || echo folder is empty
```

`/a-d` excludes subfolders (lists files only)
`>nul 2>&1` discards the output of `dir` (we don't need it, just if it is successful or not)
`&&` acts as `if previous command was successful (files were found) then`,
`||` means `if it failed (no files found) then`

(just to explain why `if exist` doesn't work: it finds `.` and `..` (current folder and parent folder), which technically are files)

Comment: Nice, it works at the very least. Thanks! 
I just add the "&& pause && goto start" at  the end to fit my code